# Cannot access fixtures from controller tests Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning how to use Ruby on Rails and having some annoying problems trying to access fixtures from a test class for a controller. Unfortunately I am getting a 'TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer' error despite following the correct approach in the Rails Testing Guide. Does anyone have any ideas on how this issue could be fixed. A sample of the code for my controller is shown below:

```
class ExerciseLogsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def show
    @exerciseLog = ExerciseLog.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do | format |
      format.json { render json: @exerciseLog }
      format.xml { render xml: @exerciseLog }
    end
  end
```

The unit test is shown below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ExerciseLogsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :exercise_logs

  test "get existing exercise log" do
    get :show, :id => 2, :format => 'json'

    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil(assigns[:exerciseLog], "Exercise log should not be nil.")
    assert_equal(exercise_logs[:log2].description, assigns[:exerciseLog].description, "Log description is not the description for log 2.")
  end
end
```

My fixtures are shown below:

```
log2:
  id: 2
  user_id: 1
  description: Walking in my lunch break.
  startTime: 2014-09-11 14:00:00
  endTime: 2014-09-11 15:00:00
  distance: 1200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It looks like the line:

```
exercise_logs[:log2].description
```

should be:

```
exercise_logs(:log2).description
```